# How do I change UILabels within my SKScene code?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uikit

I'm making an app where I have a tower in the background rendered with SpriteKit. The tower is made out of different blocks where I get the data from. I want to display this data in a UIView with different UILabels, etc...

Here's an image of the UIView and UILabels I try to link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXCkH.jpg

The problem is that I can't figure out how to link my labels and view to my SKScene code (which is not possible I know). I'm struggling to find a way to link these UI objects to my SKScene code (Show and hide the view when a certain action happens etc...)
Is there a way to link these 2?

(I know the existence of creating UI elements with SK code, but that's not what i'm looking for.)

Comment: If you want to use UI elements, why aren't you making a Single View Application which mainly works with UI elements? It's a bad idea to use UI elements into a SpriteKit application since it can produce you lots of bug while having low control over them.

Comment: I've found a way to control them within my SpriteKit code by adding them to a SharedInstance, giving me full access to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display both SKView and UIView on the same screen, you can use Container View Controllers.

You define "container views" in your storyboard and assign them to separate view controllers via "embedded" segue.

Here's a good article on doing it - https://useyourloaf.com/blog/container-view-controllers/